# AutoIt Mouse Click doesn't seem to be working

Tags: windows, batch-file, click, mouse, autoit

I made a batch file and I need it to click on the screen. I know you cannot do this with just a batch file and so I downloaded Autoit. However, everytime I run my code, it says that MouseClick is not a valid command. I downloaded AutoIt and redownloaded it but it keeps showing the same message.

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
start "" http://www.getluckee.com/games/5
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

Timeout 18

nircmd setcursor 700 400


set _number=0

:action
if %_number%==100 goto :end
%SendKeys% "{LEFT}"

%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"

%SendKeys% "{RIGHT}"

%SendKeys% "{UP}"
echo %_number%
set /a _number +=1
goto :action

:end
Timeout 5
nircmd setcursor 830 140
Timeout 2
MouseClick("left")
Timeout 10


%SendKeys% "exit{ENTER}"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```

Comment: Your script is a batch file, not an AutoIt script; how should the batch file understand AutoIt commands? thy it with an AutoIt script...

Comment: if you already use `nircmd`, why not [use it consequently](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendmouse.html)?

Comment: ... and [sendkey](http://nircmd.nirsoft.net/sendkey.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have an AutoIt function in a batch script. If you are still set on using batch, You could create a file like below:

---

### leftClick.au3

```
Sleep(250)
MouseClick("left")
```

and then

---

### myBatch.bat

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
start "" http://www.getluckee.com/games/5
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"

Timeout 18

nircmd setcursor 700 400


set _number=0

:action
if %_number%==100 goto :end
%SendKeys% "{LEFT}"

%SendKeys% "{DOWN}"

%SendKeys% "{RIGHT}"

%SendKeys% "{UP}"
echo %_number%
set /a _number +=1
goto :action

:end
Timeout 5
nircmd setcursor 830 140
Timeout 2
START leftClick.au3
Timeout 10


%SendKeys% "exit{ENTER}"

goto :EOF


@end


// JScript section

var WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell");
WshShell.SendKeys(WScript.Arguments(0));
```